# Draw edges of a polygon with OpenGL shaders

Tags: opengl-es, polygon, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I was wondering if it was possible to draw the edges of a rendered polygon with a specific color using a fragment shader, as in this example picture:

[image]

Or should I just render those separately?

Comment: How do you get this to work? I really need a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See work related on this page: http://web.archive.org/web/20120527185124/http://cgg-journal.com/2008-2/06/index.html

A vertex shader should render polygons where the distance to each edge is colored.

The difference between coloring each "cell" is explained in much detail.

Comment: Thanks, this looks nice but geometry shaders are missing in opengl es 2.0 :) any other tips?

Comment: After a bit of digging thru I realized this can be done without the geometry shader as well. Thanks for the tip.