# Draw border with fragment shader to a polygon

Tags: shader, webgl, fragment-shader

I draw a polygon and I draw border with using second draw call with drawArrays,
can I draw polygon border with fragment shader ? Only with one draw call ?

Comment: Looks like there are answers listed on the right including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035719/drawing-a-border-on-a-2d-polygon-with-a-fragment-shader?rq=1) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864748/draw-edges-of-a-polygon-with-opengl-shaders?rq=1) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760277/webgl-border-color-shader?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drawing a border on a 2d polygon with a fragment shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035719/drawing-a-border-on-a-2d-polygon-with-a-fragment-shader)

Comment: this link exist above I check but there is no geometry shader in webgl. I check some sites but I cant find absolute solution.

Comment: You don't need a geometry shader to calculate the barycentric coordinates, you can just add a vertex attribute and rely on the interpolation.

Comment: You mean calculate barycentric coordinates on cpu and bind to shader as attribute. I did not think this way I understand know. Thanks for that I want to try this. I am very busy but when I try I will share.